# Vectors & Tetrahedrons: Show that $P^2 = B^2 + R^2 + G^2 + 2BR \cos ∠(b, r) + 2RG \cos ∠(r, g) + 2GB \cos ∠(g, b).$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Show that
$$P^2 = B^2 + R^2 + G^2 - 2BR \cos ∠(B, R) - 2RG \cos ∠(R, G) - 2GB \cos ∠(G, B).$$
Here, ∠(B, R) denotes the angle between the two faces coloured blue and red, and similarly for the
other two angles in this formula. This formula is a three-dimensional counterpart of a very famous
trigonometric identity for triangles. Which identity is that?

I don't know how to go about this question, this is a part of a long answer question, can anyone please help me through this please!

Comment: Please define all letters that appear (and then submit). There is no color that can be seen in the post. Please give a first try, own thoughts, so that a potential answerer can fit to the level either a full proof or a hint.

Answer (score 0):

This is  **Al-Kashi theorem** (or the law of cosines) in the euclidean space.
You can check  p. 133 of this book :

> Casey, John (1889). A Treatise on Spherical Trigonometry: And Its Application to Geodesy and Astronomy with Numerous Examples. London: Longmans, Green, & Company.